# Shell script: unexpected operator for -ne

Tags: bash, sh

I have a shell script where I want to check if it's being run by root. If it's not then I set the variable `SUDO='sudo'` to prepend to subsequent commands. That way the user gets one nice permission denied error message from the shell and if they're running with sudo, it properly does its business. However, for the following code I get:

`myscript.sh: [: -ne: unexpected operator`

Code is:

```
#!/bin/sh

SUDO=""
if [ $EUID -ne 0 ]; then
    SUDO='sudo'
fi
```

I am running it like: `sh myscript.sh` as **this is not a bash script**. This is not an issue of sh vs bash afaik. The shebang says `/bin/sh` and I'm running it with `sh`.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Post more code.

Comment: That's all the code that is required. That alone in a .sh file (With hashbang of course) produces the error for me.

Comment: What do you mean, "*With hashbang of course*"? Show your actual code. That is, post a [mcve].

Comment: Are you running with `sh` or `bash`? Take a look at this post; I don't know Bash, but the error looks the same.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390131/receiving-a-permission-denied-message-when-checking-for-regex-through-shell-sc

Comment: Edited to show full code to reproduce.

Comment: What is stored in `EUID`? Is it a global environment variable?

Comment: It's still missing the part where you run this file. How are you running the script?

Comment: edited for that

Comment: Have you tried running it with bash?

Comment: hmm. When I run with bash it does not have an error. What's going on?

Comment: Your `sh` and `bash` are different shells. Bash supports `[[`; your `sh` does not.

Comment: Oh. I know they're different but didn't know about the support. Care to answer?

Comment: Using `sh` to start scripts is bad habit. Consider putting a line like `case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[12].*) echo "Requires bash 3.x or newer" >&2; exit 1;; esac` just after your script's shebang to stop people from doing it.

Comment: ...if, instead of using `sh yourscript` you run `./yourscript`, *the script itself* will be able to choose its interpreter, so you can be assured that it runs in the same interpreter it was developed and tested against. This also means you can rewrite from `sh` to, say, Python or C, and not need to tell your users to change how they invoke a program. Related: [Commandname Extensions Considered Harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/)

Comment: well, I've changed it to `/bin/sh` now. I don't want people to have to set +x before running it. Still the same error for a simple if statement.

Comment: Yes, `[[` is not part of POSIX sh, so you can never be guaranteed it will work with `/bin/sh`. It's not `if` that's the problem, it's `[[`.

Comment: As I've said above, `sh` does not support `[[`, so of course you're getting an error for that. I'm not sure what's unclear.

Comment: `[ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]`, by contrast, will be fine.

Comment: Apparently you somehow got a file named `[[` in your PATH, but it's not executable, so `sh` tries to use it (since it has no builtin implementation), but can't. Frankly, that file shouldn't be there in the first place -- the whole thing that makes `[[` special is that it's shell syntax, not a regular command, so any external implementation would be inherently buggy.

Comment: ...now you edited this into a *completely different question*. And you didn't pay attention to the quotes. I made it `"$EUID"`, not `$EUID`, for a reason: If your `/bin/sh` doesn't populated a variable named `EUID`, if you use quotes you'll get a error message that makes that more clear.

Comment: If I add the quotes I get `[: Illegal number:`

Comment: Right. Meaning that you have no EUID variable. Because bash populates that and you aren't using bash. That's a more useful error message than one about `-ne` being an unexpected operator.

Comment: Except i do have it.

Comment: Not in `/bin/sh` you don't.

Comment: Run `sh -c 'echo $EUID'`, with exactly that quoting.

Comment: gah. can echo and return it back or something?

Comment: nevermind. that didn't make sense. I need it

Comment: You could collect it out-of-process with `$(id -u)` if you only need to run on GNU systems. Or you could use bash. Why don't you do that?

Comment: Will just use bash